# Ajax is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm getting this problem with my jQuery when I type something on my input type.

There is my js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#cif").keyup(function(){
        var name = document.getElementById("cif").value;

        console.info(name);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '<?php echo site_url(); ?>register/cif',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                cif:name,
            },
            success: function (response) {
                $('#raosocial').html(response);
                if(response=="OK"){
                    return true;    
                }
                else{
                    return false;   
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I tried without $.ajax but syntax error appeared

Comment: probably using jQuery *"slim"* version that doesn't include ajax

Comment: Show your response. And also just below last `},`  where success is missing comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you aren't using the slim version of jQuery that  doesn't include `$.ajax()`.Download the full jQuery [here](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js)

Comment: I'm using this version and the same error persists.

Comment: I feel stupid. I'm working with bootstrap and I was working with two jquery versions...